# probability with continuous variables

Tags: probability

A point is chosen at random inside a triangle with height h and base of length b. What is the expected value of the perpendicular distance of the point to the base?

Comment: I understand how to calculate the expected value but I do not how to find the probability density function.

Comment: How could you know how to calculate the expected value (the answer) without first having gotten the density function?

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean that I know that I need to compute the integral of x*f(x) to calculate the expected value and I have the answer to the problem. However, I do not know how to begin the problem.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* If $H$ is the random variable telling the distance of the point to the base, then justify that if $0 \leq l \leq h$, then $P(H \leq l)$ is equal to the area of the portion of the triangle bounded between the base and the line parallel to the base at a height $l$. Remember that $f_H(l) = \frac{d}{dl} P(H \leq l)$.